# Add a list into an object from a class Python

Tags: python, list, class, object, oop

I have a class in Python 3.8

```
       class SomeClass:
            data=[]
            def __init__(self,my_list=[]):     
            for v in my_list:
                SomeClass.data.append(v)
```

Once an object is created from a list o lists like this:

```
       # The object always will be a list or a list of lists
       first_object= [['abc', 17.67, 1.5],['ijk', 9.68, 2.3],['efg', 50.3, 3.8],['xyz', 25.5, 16.2]]
```

I need that after an object is created, add a new list to the previous object and create a new one. The class should also have an option to add single lists into the object like this:

```
      second_object = first_object + ['wmk', 79, 2.3]
```

When i'm trying to do this i get this error:

```
      TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'SomeClass' and 'list'
```

How can I fix this?, thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of `SomeClass` in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your reply chepner, I've already solved it. I forgot to put this line correctly first_object= SomeClass([['abc', 17.67, 1.5],['ijk', 9.68, 2.3],['efg', 50.3, 3.8],['xyz', 25.5, 16.2]])

Answer (score 2):

you should add to the class a `__add__` function, so you can add an object to that class to do something, in this case i raised a `TypeError` if it wasn't list but you can do whatever you want

Code:

```
class SomeClass():
   def __init__(self,list1):
       self.data = list1
   def __add__(self,obj):
       if isinstance(obj,list):
           return self.data+obj
       else:
           raise TypeError("It is not a list!!")
```

so you can do:

```
classinstance = SomeClass([1,2,3,4])
classinstance+=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
print(classinstance)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @XxJames07-  it worked for me !! , I think I need to research more on magic methods.

Answer (score 0):

The class `SomeClass` is just a blueprint for how data should be stored and processed. You need to create what's called an instance of the class where you fill the class in with actual data.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self,my_list=[]):
        self.data=[]     
        for v in my_list:
            self.data.append(v)   

first_object = SomeClass([['abc', 17.67, 1.5],['ijk', 9.68, 2.3],['efg', 50.3, 3.8],['xyz', 25.5, 16.2]])
second_object = SomeClass(first_object.data + ['wmk', 79, 2.3])
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew for your time, is another great solution.